# DXA RetroFit - Model Annotations for Embedded Schemas?

Tags: dxa

I am implementing a DXA 1.7 site for an existing implementation where all my Schemas use 'Content' for the root element name.  I'm decorating the Model class with the attributes to specify the unique namespace of the Schema like so:

```
 [SemanticEntity(Prefix="s", Vocab = "uuid:5881DB87-8CB3-4550-A585-F9F2750F18F8", EntityName = "Content")]
```

What should my Embedded Schema class annotation look like?  I have this now:

```
[SemanticEntity(Vocab = CoreVocabulary, EntityName = "ContentBlockCombo")]
```

Also, I saw [this issue in the DXA 1.7](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/issues/40) regarding Embedded Schemas, where we need to use the same prefix from the Parent and Embedded Schemas.  Then, would I need to add a prefix of "s" to the Embedded Schema?  And use this for all Schemas and Embedded Schemas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes indeed, you have to use the same prefix from the Parent and Embedded Schemas otherwise mapping will not work properly. Also use this for all the schemas and embedded schemas.

So your Embedded schema will looks like  -

```
[SemanticEntity(Vocab = CoreVocabulary, EntityName = "ContentBlockCombo",Prefix="s" )]
```