# Issue with model mapping of Embedded fields on DXA 1.8

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-1.8

Recently we upgrade Tridion platform to 8.5 and DXA from 1.3 to 1.8. Although everything seemed OK at the beginning, we are having issues with model mapping of Embedded fields. All the Embedded models are just NULL with in the parent object. 
After struggling for few days, we found that renaming embedded field's root element to same of its parent(In our case its "Content") solved the issue. But We have some existing 
schema with multiple embedded fields and we can't rename both embedded fields to "Content". Tried specifying Semantic property to the embeded models but still no joy :(

```
[SemanticEntity(Vocab = CoreVocabulary, EntityName = "ContentType", Prefix = "s")]
```

I tried debugging the DXA code and I could see an issue with mapping on `DefaultModelBuilder` -> `MapFieldValues()` ->  `MapEmbeddedFields()` -> `GetFieldFromSemantics()`. The xpath is always taking `Content\Content\` insted of `Content\ContentType\` even after specifying the the entity name on Semantic property.

To me, this seems to be a mapping issue with DXA 1.8. Can someone confirm? Is there any other way to address the embedded mapping issue?

**EDIT**
Here is the complete schema.json

```
 {
    "Id": 30241,
    "RootElement": "Content",
    "Fields": [{
            "Name": "title",
            "Path": "/Content/title",
            "IsMultiValue": false,
            "Semantics": [{
                    "Prefix": "tri",
                    "Entity": "Content",
                    "Property": "title"
                }
            ],
            "Fields": []
        }, {
            "Name": "description",
            "Path": "/Content/description",
            "IsMultiValue": false,
            "Semantics": [{
                    "Prefix": "tri",
                    "Entity": "Content",
                    "Property": "description"
                }
            ],
            "Fields": []
        }, {
            "Name": "first_name_label",
            "Path": "/Content/first_name_label",
            "IsMultiValue": false,
            "Semantics": [{
                    "Prefix": "tri",
                    "Entity": "Content",
                    "Property": "first_name_label"
                }
            ],
            "Fields": []
        }, {
            "Name": "first_name_placeholder",
            "Path": "/Content/first_name_placeholder",
            "IsMultiValue": false,
            "Semantics": [{
                    "Prefix": "tri",
                    "Entity": "Content",
                    "Property": "first_name_placeholder"
                }
            ],
            "Fields": []
        }, {
            "Name": "first_name_required_message",
            "Path": "/Content/first_name_required_message",
            "IsMultiValue": false,
            "Semantics": [{
                    "Prefix": "tri",
                    "Entity": "Content",
                    "Property": "first_name_required_message"
                }
            ],
            "Fields": []
        }, {
            "Name": "last_name_label",
            "Path": "/Content/last_name_label",
            "IsMultiValue": false,
            "Semantics": [{
                    "Prefix": "tri",
                    "Entity": "Content",
                    "Property": "last_name_label"
                }
            ],
            "Fields": []
        }, {
            "Name": "last_name_placeholder",
            "Path": "/Content/last_name_placeholder",
            "IsMultiValue": false,
            "Semantics": [{
                    "Prefix": "tri",
                    "Entity": "Content",
                    "Property": "last_name_placeholder"
                }
            ],
            "Fields": []
        }, {
            "Name": "last_name_required_message",
            "Path": "/Content/last_name_required_message",
            "IsMultiValue": false,
            "Semantics": [{
                    "Prefix": "tri",
                    "Entity": "Content",
                    "Property": "last_name_required_message"
                }
            ],
            "Fields": []
        }, {
            "Name": "email_label",
            "Path": "/Content/email_label",
            "IsMultiValue": false,
            "Semantics": [{
                    "Prefix": "tri",
                    "Entity": "Content",
                    "Property": "email_label"
                }
            ],
            "Fields": []
        }, {
            "Name": "email_placeholder",
            "Path": "/Content/email_placeholder",
            "IsMultiValue": false,
            "Semantics": [{
                    "Prefix": "tri",
                    "Entity": "Content",
                    "Property": "email_placeholder"
                }
            ],
            "Fields": []
        }, {
            "Name": "email_required_message",
            "Path": "/Content/email_required_message",
            "IsMultiValue": false,
            "Semantics": [{
                    "Prefix": "tri",
                    "Entity": "Content",
                    "Property": "email_required_message"
                }
            ],
            "Fields": []
        }, {
            "Name": "subscription_types",
            "Path": "/Content/subscription_types",
            "IsMultiValue": true,
            "Semantics": [{
                    "Prefix": "tri",
                    "Entity": "Content",
                    "Property": "subscription_types"
                }
            ],
            "Fields": [{
                    "Name": "title",
                    "Path": "/Content/subscription_types/title",
                    "IsMultiValue": false,
                    "Semantics": [{
                            "Prefix": "tri",
                            "Entity": "SubscriptionType",
                            "Property": "title"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Fields": []
                }, {
                    "Name": "description",
                    "Path": "/Content/subscription_types/description",
                    "IsMultiValue": false,
                    "Semantics": [{
                            "Prefix": "tri",
                            "Entity": "SubscriptionType",
                            "Property": "description"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Fields": []
                }, {
                    "Name": "newsletter_id",
                    "Path": "/Content/subscription_types/newsletter_id",
                    "IsMultiValue": false,
                    "Semantics": [{
                            "Prefix": "tri",
                            "Entity": "SubscriptionType",
                            "Property": "newsletter_id"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Fields": []
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "Name": "summary",
            "Path": "/Content/summary",
            "IsMultiValue": false,
            "Semantics": [{
                    "Prefix": "tri",
                    "Entity": "Content",
                    "Property": "summary"
                }
            ],
            "Fields": []
        }, {
            "Name": "gdpr_consent_text_pm",
            "Path": "/Content/gdpr_consent_text_pm",
            "IsMultiValue": false,
            "Semantics": [{
                    "Prefix": "tri",
                    "Entity": "Content",
                    "Property": "gdpr_consent_text_pm"
                }
            ],
            "Fields": []
        }, {
            "Name": "cta_text",
            "Path": "/Content/cta_text",
            "IsMultiValue": false,
            "Semantics": [{
                    "Prefix": "tri",
                    "Entity": "Content",
                    "Property": "cta_text"
                }
            ],
            "Fields": []
        }, {
            "Name": "thank_you_link",
            "Path": "/Content/thank_you_link",
            "IsMultiValue": false,
            "Semantics": [{
                    "Prefix": "tri",
                    "Entity": "Content",
                    "Property": "thank_you_link"
                }
            ],
            "Fields": []
        }, {
            "Name": "error_link",
            "Path": "/Content/error_link",
            "IsMultiValue": false,
            "Semantics": [{
                    "Prefix": "tri",
                    "Entity": "Content",
                    "Property": "error_link"
                }
            ],
            "Fields": []
        }
    ],
    "Semantics": [{
            "Prefix": "tri",
            "Entity": "Content"
        }
    ]
}
```

And sematic entity is always `content`. It is supposed to be `SubscriptionType`, isn't it?

[image]

Any help appreciated!

**Issue Resolved**

As per Rick's comment, For some reason publish settigns was pointing to old version of DXA and after registering embedded type everthign worked like charm!

Comment: Is your Embeeded class inheriting from ViewModel? (or EntityBase or whatever class that is DXA's aware...)

Comment: Please provide more info. How are your (embedded) View Model Types defined? What are the root element/type names of your CM Schemas what are the field XML names? Note that the “root element name” of an embedded Schema is actually a type name. That is: you won’t see that name reflected in an XPath.  Please have a look (and share) the `BinaryData/xyz/system/mappings/schemas.json` and find the relevants Schemas there.  Also have a look at the DXA log file with DEBUG logging enabled.

Comment: Is the embedded View Model Type registered? See https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v7.1.1/GUID-FEDC295C-1D87-485E-B904-AE5596A4A802

Comment: Also try republishing the “Publish Settings” Page (to ensure that `schemas.json` is up-to-date)

Comment: In the past, there was an issue that prefixes for embedding and embedded View Model Type annotations should be the same. See also https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/17987/dxa-retrofit-model-annotations-for-embedded-schemas  (note that the question is about *retrofit mode* which you probably don't use, but it mentions use of prefixes).

Comment: Hi @RickPannekoek. No, we are not using _retrofit mode_ and find the details in the edit section. I tried registering embedded type as well but no joy!

Comment: Did you republish the "Publish Settings" Page after upgrading to DXA 1.8?  IIRC, since DXA 1.7, embedded Schema fields should have two semantics (in `schemas.json`): one with Entity = {Embedded Schema Root Element Name} and one with Entity = {Embedding Schema Root Element Name}

Comment: Yes, republished the page and double cheked on schema.joas as well. Parent entity name is `Content` and embeded is `subscriptionType`. So, I see in the `DefaultModelBuilder()` always gets the parent `EntityName` (i"Content" ) even for the embeded type `subscriptionType`. @RickPannekoek Can you please let me know what should be the Semantic decoration for both model claass?

Comment: so when it goes to `MapEmbeddedFields()` to mapp the embedded type values its unable to find the Semantics and its logging error : `Property SubscriptionType.Title cannot be mapped to a CM field of SemanticSchema 71210 (Content). Semantic properties: :title.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that your `schemas.json` is incomplete.

In DXA 1.7, the semantic mapping was refactored (in order to introduce *refrofit mode*). As part of that refactoring, mapping of embedded fields was changed. Since DXA 1.7, you should see multiple semantics for embedded fields in `schemas.json`: one representing the embedded schema and one representing the embedding schema (and even more if you have multiple levels of embedding).

This change in semantic mapping both on CM side and in the Web Application is supposed to be backwards compatible (no changes to your View Model types should be needed), but you do have to ensure that you republish `schemas.json` by means of republishing the ”Publish Setting” Page after upgrading to DXA 1.7 or higher.

You are saying that you don’t see multiple semantics for embedded schema fields in `schemas.json`, even after republishing the “Publish Settings” Page. That makes me wonder whether you have properly upgraded your DXA on CM-side.

Comment: Hi Rick Pannekoek, it was my bad! Included complete schema for the component now. now. I don't think there is an issue with schema.json. Could you please confirm how do I need to specify the semantic decorators on viewmodel class for both embedded and embedding models?

Comment: I do think there is an issue with your schemas.json. Check, for example, how the `/Content/subscription_tyoes/title` field is defined. It has only one semantics (`SubscriptionType:title`), but should have two (also `Content:title`).

Comment: is there a way to check if DXA 1.8 on CM side is properly updated? What/where do you think could be the issue?

Comment: Thanks @Rick Pannekoek! Publish settigns was pointing to old version of DXA and after registering embedded type everthign worked magically! :)